# How to use Django session variable in models.py

Tags: python, django

I wanna use the Django session variable on models.py file. How can I do it?

I want to get the user's Pincode/zip and have to run a query using that.

```
pin_code = #wanna get from session
price = ProductPrice.objects.get(product=self.pk, pincode=pin_code)
```

I need to get Pincode from the session.

Comment: You need to provide a more detailed question and some code if you wish to get an answer

Comment: Is this query being run in a view or on a model method? If it's in a view it's simpler, can you share the view?

Comment: It is run on the model method.

Comment: How and where is the model method being called? Can you share the view and the model?

Comment: Yeah, sure. 

It is being called in template.

<td id="item-price-{{ item.id }}">{{ item.get_price }} </td>

and in model, 

    def get_price(self):
        pin_code = #get pin
        price_q = ProductPrice.objects.get(product=self.pk, pin_code=pin_code)
        price = price_q.price if price_q.price is not None else self.price
        return price

Comment: So you have a list/table of products and you want to show a price for each product that is dynamic based on the user's pin/zip? Will this method be called in many places?

Comment: Yeah, That's it. It will be called in 3-4 places on same page.

Comment: Can you share the view that renders this page?

Comment: Here it is, 
class ProductList(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(show_on_site=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model method you don't have access to the request so you do not have access to the session. One way that you could call the method with the session is to [add a template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) that passes the value from the session to your method

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def price(context, product):
    return product.get_price(pin_code=context.request.session.get('pin_code'))
```

In your template you would use the following, if the above code was added to a file with the path `app_name/templatetags/product_tags.py`

```
{% load product_tags %}

{% price item %}
```

[Docs on where to put custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)

Comment: what is the register import please? thank you

Comment: Can you give more information where to set this code please? thank you

Comment: @M.Mariscal I've made an edit. The simple answer is to add your custom tags in a folder named "templatetags" in your app - `app_name/templatetags/product_tags.py` for the above example

Comment: Excuse me sir, link is broken, where to put the first code? on the model or on the view? it is not clear

Comment: @M.Mariscal fixed link